# Android - what is limiting the definitions in the sample SearchableDictionary

Tags: android, search, textview, sample

I am trying to implement parts of the SearchableDictionary from the android developers samples.  I changed the definitions list and for a long definition the text is cut off, I tried to make it scrollable thinking it may be limited that way but after scrolling I realized there must be a character cutoff.

I used this to make it scroll:

```
TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
definition.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and

```
android:maxLines="3"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Since this is most likely not the limiting factor what is stopping the definition TextView from displaying the entire definition?

Edit:

I am learning towards thinking that this is a limitation of characters and not a scrolling issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
definition.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and

```
android:maxLines="3"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

were indeed the answer, the text was being cutoff by a dash in the random text that I put in the definitions as an example.  Once the dash "-" was deleted all appeared correctly, and with the addition of the above code scrolling was achieved.